# How to store all kind of words forms in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store all kind of forms of each word, or connect existing words somehow.
The problem is what different part of speech has different forms.
From database I need to get full word info with php.

For example, if I need to get all form of `be`, than I should get

- 1st person singular present tense - `am`
- 2nd person singular present tense - `are`
- 3rd person singular present tense - `is`
- present participle - `being`
- 1st person singular past tense - `was`
- 2nd person singular past tense - `were`
- past participle - `been`

And if I need to get info about noun, for example `project`, than I need to get its plural form - `projects`.

Same for other kind of forms.

The only way that comes to my mind is to create table where will be columns for all kind of forms and store single words to them(or word ids). And if the word does not have such forms then insert null.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? What will you do with this kind of database ?

Comment: @AymDev maybe he is going to develop English grammar site (:

Comment: It's site for learning English

Comment: You have a choice. Either create a separate table for each part of speech, or have lots of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look into Lexical Databases.

Have a look at [this](http://www.solarix.ru/sql-dictionary-sdk-en.shtml) - it's an English and Russian Vocabulary and Morphology database (many different example db's including MySQL).  Specifically what you are asking about is the morphology of words.  Also you can look into different Natural Language Processing libraries.  [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) is great for Python.

This should get you started.